# Where can I find my own server's DNS records? Need to update it for a third party mail delivery system - SparkPost?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, centos7, dkim

I have a forum running which occasionally sends out emails to registered users. We are switching our forum engine from vBulletin to Discourse. While configuring Discourse, I need to provide the credentials for the SMTP server. So I created an account on Spark Post which one of the recommended email providers for Discourse: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-email.md.

While setting up the account for SparkPost, I added the domain for my forum, say - example.com as the sending domain on SparkPost. Now it asks me to verify the ownership of my domain by adding a TXT record (DKIM - DomainKeys Identified Mail) to my DNS records. My problem is that I do not understand where are the DNS records on my server. My guess is that I need to edit the DNS records on my DNS service provider.

The forum is hosted on a CentOS 7 server which is owned by us. We are NOT using any service provider like GoDaddy, etc.

I have looked on the internet a lot and just can't seem to find a clear answer. I know this is might be a very basic question but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dig`. For example:

```
$ dig NS serverfault.com +short
ns-860.awsdns-43.net.
ns-1135.awsdns-13.org.
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
```

You can also verify this by checking the Name Server records for your domain at your registry:

```
$ whois serverfault.com | grep "Name Server"
Name Server: NS-1135.AWSDNS-13.ORG
Name Server: NS-860.AWSDNS-43.NET
Name Server: NS-CLOUD-C1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Name Server: NS-CLOUD-C2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
```

This example is a bit more complicated than most due the fact that Server Fault and all of its sister sites actually use [two DNS providers](http://blog.serverfault.com/2017/01/09/surviving-the-next-dns-attack/). In this case, they're using AWS and Google Cloud. In most cases, the results of the above commands will just point to a single DNS provider.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in that you'll need to update your DNS records through your DNS provider - whoever you purchased your domain from. Go to that organization and log in. In that administration panel, you should be able to do things like update your DNS records, such as adding a TXT record. Below is an example screenshot from NameCheap.

So in your case you'll create a TXT record with the value being your key. If it's done correctly, and DNS has had some time to update, you should see this key when you do `dig txt <your domain here>`.

The link below is an example screenshot of editing DNS records in NameCheap
https://namecheap.simplekb.com//SiteContents/2-7C22D5236A4543EB827F3BD8936E153E/media/addnewrecord.png